# c# multithreaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am somewhat new to c# and multithreading so I may be making a silly mistake here but I can't seem to figure this out.  I have an application that creates an array of threads based on the number of machines is discovers on my network, then for each machine creates a thread which executes a function I have created.  After exiting the for loop I create another thread which runs another function.  My functions works perfectly fine and there is no issue there, the problem is for some reason after exiting the for loop and proceeding to create the next thread, my application jumps back into the for loop and the index is now out of range and causes an exception to be thrown.  I hope I am explaining this clearly, I am baffled at why this is happening as I have no idea why when finished the for loop it would execute a line of code and jump back in.  Anyways here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
        smThread = new Thread[networkedComputers.Count];

        for (UInt16 i = 0; i < networkedComputers.Count; i++)
        {
            smThread[i] = new Thread(delegate() { sm.RunServerMonitorPerMachine(networkedComputers[i].ToString()); });
            smThread[i].Start();
        }

        dailyThread = new Thread(dailyEvents);
        dailyThread.Start();
```

Comment: I might check out Tasks instead.  I think they are a bit more straightforward.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx

Comment: This isn't an answer but in general I think it would be better to use the TPL here. C# makes things much easier for you than C++ or C by managing low level details itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Do you touch the `networkedComputers` array in another thread? It is possible that `networkedComputer.Count` changes while you are in the `for` loop.

Comment: are you sure the created thread is not throwing an exception? it could look in the debugger like you jump back into the for loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your problem is right here:

```
networkedComputers[i].ToString()
                   ^
```

You may be expecting to pass the value of `i` to the thread when you do this, but actually, you pass a reference to `i`. This reference updates as you loop, so when the thread actually executes, it most likely will not be the value you expect it to. (Google keywords: captured variable)

The solution is to make a copy of the value before passing it into the thread. This copy will not be updated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < networkedComputers.Count; i++)
{
    int tmp = i;
    smThread[i] = new Thread(delegate() { sm.RunServerMonitorPerMachine(networkedComputers[tmp].ToString()); });
    smThread[i].Start();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation, but isn't `i` never be more than `networkedComputers.Count`, and hence it should never cause an `OutOfRangeException` ? Or is `i` shortly one higher when the `for` loop checks it?

Comment: After the loop is completed, `i` will remain out of range after the check.

Comment: Could it even be gone as it runs out of scope?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Nope, because capturing the variable keeps it in scope, and it is not destroyed until later.

Comment: This seems to solve my problem.  My code works now, however I have created a windows service as I want this code to be constantly running in the background.  When I run it on my local machine the service works great, however when place on a machine on the network it doesn't seem to execute any of the code.  Are there any known issues with threads and executing code remotely?  I am having difficulties debugging because I can't step through the service code.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the captured loop variable is most likely your issue as Kendall Frey has pointed out. However, as some of the other commenters on your post have suggested this might be a good case for looking into C#s Task Parallelism Library which handles a lot of these things for you. Your code would look something like this:

```
for (UInt16 i = 0; i < networkedComputers.Count; i++) {
    int count = i;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => sm.RunServerMonitorPerMachine(networkedComputers[count].ToString());
}

Task.Factory.StartNew(() => dailyEvents());
```

The benefit of this is that you don't have to worry about managing a thread pool as the tasks are queued up and picked up as soon as a thread is available to execute them. The other thing to consider is that its not much more work to enforce that your dailyEvents task is not executed until all of the tasks inside your for loop have completed. This is something that you don't have implemented in your current solution (but by the looks of things I assume its what you were going for);

Comment: I see a captured variable!

Comment: I will give the task library a try, I can't wait until the functions in the for loop are done because it is an ongoing process that I used to record perfmon data, thus they are never done unless I stop the service from running.

Comment: @KendallFrey ya I gave you credit for pointing out the error with his original implementation just wanted to show that the TPL was a nice way of handling a threading problem like this in C#

Comment: I should have mentioned this, I have VS 2005 so the task parallelism library is not an option as it is in .NET framework 4.5

Comment: TPL has been around since .NET 4.0 at least but that is unfortunate :( It certainly can help to make life easier